# Adding hand drawing and shapes to an image in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF C# application and need to do the following :

- Open an image within the application (a .png)
- Add resizable shapes on top of it (rectangles, ellipses, etc.)
- Allow the user to do some free hand drawing
- Add text boxes anywhere on the image

Is it feasible in C#? Is there a library that does precisely that, whom I'm not aware of? I've found tools to open images and others to draw from scratch, but not both. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly feasible and there're many examples with sources. Look at [that](https://wpfpaint.codeplex.com/) one.

Comment: Alright, my idea was to use a WPF canvas object, to set the image as a background and to use the `WindowFrameBrush`, looks easier your way